# Unity3d - How to create a world generator like in OpenTTD?

Tags: random, unity-game-engine, generator

I am trying some things out in Unity3d, and I stumbled onto not being able to create a simple world generator. Basicaly I want the world generator to create a world similar to the world generation of OpenTTD (only for the terrain & water, not the buildings or forests or anything else).

The problem I encountered is that I can only come with things that end more in the direction of a Minecraft like world generation, which is exactly what I do not want. I generaly end up with some kind of minefield of blocks, instead of a nice world like OpenTTD.

I wonder if anyone has experience with world generation and is able to point me in the correct direction.

I don't have any code to show unfortunately, because I deleted my code in rages of fury of many failures.

I am sorry if I posted this in the wrong place, but it seemed to only logical place.

Comment: http://vcs.openttd.org/svn/browser/trunk/src/genworld.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Use LibNoise to generate worlds.  [Here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/68764-LibNoise-Ported-to-Unity) is one ported to unity.  I am using it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QFNvf07LVI) but without a gradient or anything so it doesnt ever cut off to make the "Terrain".  The actual C++ libnoise has plenty of tutorials on how to generate terrains, [c++ libnoise link](http://libnoise.sourceforge.net/)

My voxel Speed Test:

```
    Perlin perlin = new Perlin((double)frequency, (double)lacunarity, (double)persistence, octaves, seed, QualityMode.High);
    RidgedMultifractal fractal = new RidgedMultifractal((double)frequency, (double)lacunarity, octaves, seed, QualityMode.High);

    ModuleBase noise = new Add(perlin, fractal);

    for (int x = 0; x < chunkSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < chunkSize; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < chunkSize; z++)
            {


                if (noise.GetValue(global) < .5) // or if you want it to look like terrain change to (chunkPos.y * chunkSize) + y <= (Noise.GetValue(global + 1) / 2) * height
                {
                    //add here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```